# Can't set permission "read_requests" on the first loggin

Tags: permissions, facebook-login

The permission "read_requests" can be set on first Login when using FacebookSDK (v3.0.2) in my android application.
But it can't be set after using the FacebookSDK newer than v3.0.2. 
The code is as described below. Is there any wrong with the code?

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("read_requests", "read_mailbox", "manage_notifications"); 
OpenRequest openRequest =
            new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(mLonginCallback).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS).setRequestCode(REQUEST_CODE_AUTH_ACTIVITY)
                    .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);

mSession.openForPublish(openRequest);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: never heard of read_requests, don´t you mean read_stream?

Comment: The read_requests permission is required to view the current person's received friend requests. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friendrequests)

Comment: read_requests permission seems to be removed after API v2.1. Does someone know how to get a person's pending friend requests by using the latest android FacebookSDK?

Comment: ah, sorry. i did not know that permission. but i am pretty sure there is no way with v2.1. you can´t accept/decline friend requests with the API, so it´s not really necessary to be able to read the pending ones with the API.

Comment: Thanks, luschn. I just want to get the count of a person's friend requests.